# How to execute one test before every component test in Angular?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So, the problem is I want to execute this test in every component test suite. And I don't want to duplicate this code inside every component.spec.ts file.

It is a test for checking accessibility violations with axe:

```
it('should have less than one axe violations', async () => {
   await fixture.detectChanges();
   const element = await fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
   const axeResults = await AxeCoreHelper.run(element);
   expect(AxeCoreHelper.toHaveLessThanXViolations(axeResults, 1)).toBeTrue();
});
```

Could be the best approach to create a class, and then inherit from it in every test suite?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, you can probably create a class. However, the following worked for me.

Create a new file called `base-test.ts` with an exported function.

```
export const testBeforeEveryTest = () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    expect(2).toBe(2);
  });
}
```

In a test file:

```
import { testBeforeEveryTest } from './where/test/before/every/test/is';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  testBeforeEveryTest(); // it should run expect 2 to be 2. You can put your test there.
});
```

You may have to play around with `tsconfig.spec.json` to include `base-test.ts` and to not get red squigglies on Jasmine utilities (`it, expect`). For me, I got red squiggly for `expect` but it still worked.